# Being cheap with/ about?

Tags: prepositions

I don't want to spend too much money on phones. May I say

> I am cheap with phones

or

> I am cheap about phones

I have come across a sentence that says

> I am cheap for certain things

Does that mean I can say

> I am cheap for phones

or can I say

> I am cheap on phones

Comment: Using *cheap* in this sense is not idiomatic in my estimation. There are a large number of expressions you could use from being *economical* to being *mean* or *tight-fisted*, but *cheap* is not normally used in that way.

Comment: @WS2 In the United States it certainly is used in this sense.

Comment: Though a little wordier, it's more idiomatic and natural-sounding to say, for example  "I am cheap when it comes to my phone". Or "When it comes to phones, I'm cheap!" Or "I'm a cheapskate when it comes to paying for phone service."

Comment: @MattSamuel Sorry, I hadn't realised that. *Cheap* is used in many senses, but that's a new one on me.

Comment: @KristinaLopez The OP seems to have thrown up one of those occasional Anglo/American howlers - like *randy* (an innocent boy's name in America, but having an insatiable sexual desire in Britain). Being *cheap* is not something any self-respecting British person would want to be accused of, let alone admit to.

Comment: @WS2 Well I've been in the UK several times and I always choose the wrong word there. Apparently nobody's ever heard of silverware or restrooms!

Comment: @WS2 Calling yourself "cheap" isn't as bad as someone else calling you "cheap".  Still, if I were talking about myself I might soften it by saying, "I'm frugal" or "cost-conscious". lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, "I'm cheap when it comes to phones." "I'm cheap on phones" also could be used, but "I'm cheap for phones" seems ungrammatical.

Comment: I don't think that would work in British English.

Comment: Why don't you think it would work in British English, Mr Chasly?